# Mod_rewrite to use virtual folders

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Im strugling with .htaccess and cant figure this out

I have that link: `index.php?metoda=blog_detale&id=1`

I want to that whis link could be accessed by this: /wiadomosci/[name-of-a-post]-[id]

and 
[name-of-a-post] is ([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)
[id] is ([0-9]+)

wiadomosci is virtual folder not present in dir tree

Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^wiadomosci/([\w-]+)-([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?metoda=$1&id=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```